# Linking prebuilt object in Arduino IDE

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, arduino

I am trying to compile an arduino program.

I want to have some files already compiled, everything except sketch. I already modified arduino IDE for compiling just uncompiled files but I need to have .h files of all of my files.

Is it possible to compile in CPP a file having the others in .o and without .h?

I don't want that anybody could see my files or code including .h.

If it is possible, I will start to check arduino code looking for how to modify it but if it isn't I will have to look for another way to do it.

Comment: In theory, you could **link** your object file with those already exist. However, without even a *header** file, the `.cpp` file has no knowledge of whatever in your **object** file. So what's the point of providing such an invisible library?!

Comment: Edited your title to reflect that what you want to do is to link an already compiled file.   This is definitely possible (if you provide a header with just function prototypes, etc) for the Arduino as a target (using a Makefile build for example), however getting the IDE to do it may be tricky - the IDE seems designed to encourage libraries which are open source and user improvable.

Comment: @ChrisStratton of course it's possible. But the newly-compiled `.cpp` has none of those identifiers in *object* files defined and therefore cannot use them (maybe one can still use *ugly* pointers)....

Comment: External references in source files are of course undefined as far as the compiler is concerned, and remain so in the object files it outputs.  It's the linker which needs to resolve them.  All the compiler needs are appropriate function prototypes, global declarations, typedefs, etc.

Comment: I want to have a program running down the program in sketch, so thats the point in having an invisible library.  I will try to make some test in command line and after export to arduino IDE. I know it is developed for open source and it will need many modifications

Comment: You can source files into .a files. You can then include calls to these .a files. These then need to be put into the compilers path and linked in. There are a few questions about this in Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 4):

Arduino uses C++, compiled C++ function names are mangled to include the parameter types in the object(.o) file.  The only way for the user's code to be compiled with compatible name mangling is for it to have the full function declarations at compile time.

So you must at least provide a header file that includes the full function declarations of any functions the user will call.  This can't be secret, it is your API, the user can't use it if you don't tell them about it.

What you don't need to include in the public header files are the declarations or definitions of internal private functions or data types.

So create a `library_public.h` file that includes only the declarations the user should know about and provide this with your .o files.  And then create a `library_private.h` that has all of your secret stuff in it.  Your private source code would include both.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I will do it in that way

Comment: Just another question related to this. I have some functions in "secret" files which are called by "public" functions. Can I also include the secrect ones in library_privare.h?